# Have I computed this definite integral correctly?

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, definite-integrals

$$ \int^\frac{\pi}{6}_0 \tan^38x\sec^38x \ dx
$$ $ u = 8x $ $$ \frac{1}{8} \int^{u =\frac{8\pi}{6}}_{u = 8(0)} \tan^3u\sec^3u \ du \ $$ $$ = \frac{1}{8} \int ^\frac{4\pi}{3}_{0} (\tan u\sec u)^2 \sec u\tan u \ du$$
$ v = \sec u $ $$ = \frac{1}{8} \int ^{v = \sec(\frac{4\pi}{3})}_{v = \sec(0)} v^2(v^2-1) \ dv$$ $$ = \frac{1}{8} [\frac{v^5}{5}-\frac{v^3}{3}]^{-2}_1 $$ $$ = -\frac{9}{20}$$

I'm sorry that I have to ask, but integral sites and my calculator suggest that -9/20 is wrong. Could someone tell me if I've made a mistake in my working

Comment: I honestly can't see what I did wrong...

Comment: The problem is with the interval you are integrating over. Look out for the vertical asymptotes!

Comment: this integral doesn't exist.

Comment: @David Quinn I also want to know about vertical asymptotes. What was that?

Comment: @DavidQuinn Should've noticed that. It seems the member Ronan was implying there was something incorrect about my workings. Assuming this was an indefinite integral or over an interval where this function was continuous, would my workings have been correct?

Comment: Looks ok to me so you can obtain the indefinite integral...

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh $ \displaystyle \int^b_a f(x) \ dx = L $ iff $f(x) $ is continuous over the interval $[a,b]$

Answer (score 0):

Before computing such an integral, you should first check if it converges.
In your case, the value $x=\dfrac{\pi}{16}\in\left[0;\dfrac{\pi}{6}\right]$ is clearly a problematic point, as
$$\lim_{\underset{x\neq\frac{\pi}{16}}{x\to\frac{\pi}{16}}}(\sec(8x))=+\infty$$
Let $f\colon x\mapsto\tan^3(8x)\sec^3(8x)$ and let us check whether $\displaystyle\int_0^\frac{\pi}{16}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ converges.
In fact, there are many ways to check the latter convergence. I chose to simply compute an antiderivative $F$ of $f$ and then find out its limit at point $x=\dfrac{\pi}{16}$.
We can take for example
$$F\colon x\mapsto-\frac{1}{240}\sec^5(8x)\left(5\cos(16x)-1\right)$$
One can now easily prove that the limit of $F$ when $x$ tends to $\dfrac{\pi}{16}$ is equal to $+\infty$, and it follows that $\displaystyle\int_0^\frac{\pi}{16}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ diverges.
As
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{6}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\underbrace{\int_0^\frac{\pi}{16}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}_{I_1}+\underbrace{\int_\frac{\pi}{16}^\frac{\pi}{6}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}_{I_2}$$
converges iff $I_1$ and $I_2$ converge (by definition), we can finally conclude that
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{6}\tan^3(8x)\sec^3(8x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
does not converge.